# Handling HTTP 500 in javascript fetch catch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using an API that if an internal server error occurs the details of the error are returned in JSON format.

Currently, I have the following code that can handle a successful response but in the case of an HTTP 500 response, the status text is logged in the console:

```
function checkStatus(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

fetch("/api/url")
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // process success JSON here
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

How would I handle the JSON that is returned in the HTTP 500 response, so the properties could be used in `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML` assignments?

Comment: Does it help you think differently about the scenario to know that [`Response.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) is `true` only when [`Response.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) is a value in the range `200`–`299`?

Answer (score 1):

The json contained in the reponse is always in `response.json()` even in case of an error 500.

In your example you are throwing an error containing only `statusText`.

You could instead do something like that:

```js
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    response.json().then((jsonError: any) => {
      // your code to handle the json, for example:
      if (error.status === 500) {
            throw new HttpError('Something went wrong', jsonError);
        }
    }
  }
  return response;
}
```

You could for example create a new class of error that takes in a property corresponding to your `jsonError`:

```js
export class HttpError extends Error {
    public jsonError: any;
    constructor(error: Error, jsonError: any) {
        super(error.message);
        this.jsonError = jsonError;
    }
}
```

Then you could use the `jsonError` property in your `catch()` method.